# How to download files from SQL Server Management using asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

can anyone help me with the codes on how to download an uploaded file, whereby the file is in csv format and is being stored in SQL Server Management. I am currently using asp.net, c#, and am doing this in Microsoft Visual Studio. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Is the actual CSV file in an Image/Varbinary(MAX) column in your table?

Answer (score 0):

The way you can do it is open the CSV in Excel, open the table you want to add to in SQL MS, and then just copy and paste. Should work as long as the number of columns is the same.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, but I'm using codes in order for my website to download the csv file. For example, I have a download button, and I have to write the codes in the event handler of the download button, i'm using c# btw

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the data, create a comma separated list in a string and then stream that to the users browser.

```
StringBuilder sw = new StringBuilder();
//assuming you have a datatable named dt
int NumColumns = dt.Columns.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < NumColumns; i++)
    {
        sw.Write(dt.Columns[i]);
        if (i < dt.Columns.Count - 1)
        {
            sw.Write(",");
        }
    }

    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
    // write = the rows.
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
   {
        for (int i = 0; i < NumColumns; i++)
        {
            sw.Write(dr[i].ToString());
            if (i < NumColumns - 1)
            {
                sw.Write(",");
            }
        }
        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
    }



    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=file.csv");
    Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
    Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Write(sw.NewLine);
    Response.End();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks man, but if I want to download the csv to the user's computer, and not the browser? What should I do? Sorry I ask too much cos I'm very new with this

Comment: So are you looking at providing the user with some sort of executable or installed program to do this? Sorry, I just assumed that you were going to do this through a web app.

Comment: I want to let the user of the website to download the csv file through the web application, can I do that?

Comment: The: _Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=file.csv");_  line will tell the browser to download it as an attachment rather than trying to view it inline.